# Access of Lua functions from C# via LuaInterface

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I have a problem with LuaInterface accessing Lua functions from C#.

If I have a LuaFunction defined like this

```
function object:OnEvent()
  -- Do something
end
```

this could be access from C# with a normal call like

```
(object["OnEvent"] as LuaFunction).Call();
```

without parameters. But if you look at the definition of the function in Lua, I used a ":" to define the function. I could rewrite it like this, which is the same:

```
function object.OnEvent(self)
  -- Do something
end
```

So far, all is Ok. But now, I replace OnEvent by another function.

```
function Replacement(self)
  -- Do something other
end

object.OnEvent = Replacement
```

And now I get a problem. In this case, I had to call the function with a parameter (for self). If I didn't do this, I get an error.

I could solve this problem by two things:

1. Say LuaInterface, that it should call methods with ":" each time
   with a parameter for self.
2. I could retrive from LuaInterface, how
   many parameters this function needs.

But, how to do one of this things?

Thank you.